# Run python script in Atom

Tags: python, windows-10, atom-editor

Is it possible to run a python script with atom, in another window? It may use any package, at long as it works with python 3 and tkinter. I tried the script package, but I couldn't find the option. Is there somebody of you who got it working?

Comment: Check this [Atom python run](https://atom.io/packages/atom-python-run)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and I checked it out but it didn't work how I hoped it worked. I really want it so it can stay open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think ATOM is an IDE. It is just an Editor.

It cannot create a Development environment. Your best option is use the built-in "Terminal".

Even if there exist some package, all it could do is execute a command line, which is similar to manually running the file on the command line.
Running Python on Eclipse can give you a feel, that you execute by clicking the "Run", but it masks the command line actually.

Only 'notebook' can do the wonders of python kernel.

Comment: Atom can be used as an IDE for python.  It has several extensions which enable Atom to do many things. Atom is very useful in that if your running virtual environments for python, which you should if you have more than 1 version of Python, Atom will use the version of python defines for whatever virtual environment is actived.  Atom also offers some very useful features when used as an IDE.  But Atom is basically a text editor as stated by NiLInfinite.

Comment: The is an extension called script. if you load it you can use that to run your scripts.